# Why got error, if not write '&' in the foreach loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, c++11, foreach

I am just making some code for my program, but eventually I forgot to write a little symbol and got error, Please, help to understand what's wrong here.

The code I wanted to write -

```
int arr[3][2] = {with some values};
for(auto &i : arr) {
    for(int j : i)
        cout << j << " " ;
    cout << endl;
}
```

The code I wrote accidentlly -

```
int arr[3][2] = {with some values};
for(auto i : arr) {   // just forgot to write (&) and got error 
    for(int j : i)
        cout << j << " " ;
    cout << endl;
}
```

**The thing I know** - Reference ("&") operator make us able to change the values inside the loop itself.
But what is the error in second loop, I mean it can deep copy the array objects, one by one, and create separate objects and then iterate over them, though we will not be able to change array values itself.

**Error I got** -  `'std::end' declared here 1244 | end(const valarray<_Tp>& __va)`

Comment: You probably ran into *array pointer decay*.  A pointer cannot be used as a ranged-based **for** range expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element of `arr` is an array (`int[2]`). The problem is that if you declare `i` as non-reference, it'll be deduced as type `int*`, the array would decay to pointer and set to `i` during iteration. Pointers can't be used with [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). The error message from `for(int j : i)` is trying to tell you that there's no `std::end` declared for `int*`.

If you declare `i` as reference, it'll be reference to array (`int(&)[2]`), no array-to-pointer conversion (array decay) happens.

Answer (score 0):

`auto i` means you want a value.

The value type you get from iterating `int arr[3][2]` is `int[3]`, an array.

Due to legacy C reasons, raw arrays cannot be copied using copy construction or assignment.  So when you do

```
auto i = arr[0];
```

instead of an `int i[2] = arr[0]` (illegal), you get `int* i = arr[0]` through a process known as "decay", also inherited from C.

Meanwhile, `for(auto& i : arr)` *doesn't* make a copy, it makes a reference to the sub-array.

In short, the first one is:

```
int * i = arr[0];
```

the second is

```
int(&i)[2] = arr[0];
```

then you try to iterate over `i`.

In the first case, `for( int j : i )` is nonsense, as a pointer doesn't know how much memory it holds.  In the second, the reference to the array does know how memory it holds.  So you can iterate in the second, not the first.

---

As a general rule, I find

```
for (auto&& i : arr)
```

to be the cleanest most general way to iterate.  Sometimes:

```
for (auto const& i : arr)
```

if you want to state "I don't alter the data".  Even there, I'd prefer

```
for (auto&& i : std::as_const(arr))
```

as that handles some corner cases, like `vector<bool>` better.  (Sadly, if `arr` is an expression producing the buffer, `as_const` doesn't work well; reference lifetime extension fails)

Comment: @songyuanyao Sure, sounds right.  Sorry, wasn't doing the proper C right-left type deconstruction thing.